# Copying std::vector<char> into dynamic char array adds unexpected characters

Tags: c++, vector

I'm making functions to turn (is that the correct verb?) a char[] into a std::vector and the other way around. The code in t_main is a test I'm running to see if the functions work correctly.

```
typedef std::vector<char> string_t;

static string_t CharArrayToVector(const char string[])
{
    string_t vectorString;
    for (int i = 0; string[i] != NULL; ++i)
        vectorString.push_back(string[i]);
    return vectorString;
}

static char* VectorToCharArray(string_t string)
{
    char *new_string = new char[string.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < string.size(); i++)
        new_string[i] = string.at(i);
    return new_string;
}
```

the main function:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << VectorToCharArray(CharArrayToVector("hello world!1"));
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    return 0;
}
```

The following code prints "hello world!1" and then a bunch of characters.

The characters are the same every run (4 subscript 2s, 8 1/2 signs, then three sets of opaque rectangle then euro sign, and finally another rectangle), and stay the same even if I change what I'm printing. Debugging shows that the extra characters are added when I initialize the array (char *new_string = new char[string.size()];)

What causes those extra characters and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: You're aware that every C-string has to stop with `\NUL`? You need to `.push_back(0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to append a `'\0'` character to your `char *`.  Also, don't forget to allocate enough space for that extra character.

But why are you doing this?  This functionality is already built into the std::string.

Comment: *"But why are you doing this?"* Probably learning and experimentation. Which is actually good: now user1461837 will always remember that null-terminated strings need a `'\0'`.